# Adding numbers from two data frames in Deedle using multi key index

Tags: c#, csv, deedle

I am new to Deedle. I searched everywhere looking for examples that can help me to complete the following task:

1. Index data frame using multiple columns (3 in the example - Date, ID and Title)
2. Add numeric columns in multiple data frames together (Sales column in the example)
3. Group and add together sales occurred on the same day

My current approach is given below. First of all - it does not work because of the missing values and I don't know how to handle them easily while adding data frames. Second - I wonder if there is a better more elegant way to do it.

```
// Remove unused columns
var df = dfRaw.Columns[new[] { "Date", "ID", "Title", "Sales" }];

// Index data frame using 3 columns 
var dfIndexed = df.IndexRowsUsing(r => Tuple.Create(r.GetAs<DateTime>("Date"), r.GetAs<string>("ID"), r.GetAs<string>("Title")) );

// Remove indexed columns
dfIndexed.DropColumn("Date");
dfIndexed.DropColumn("ID"); 
dfIndexed.DropColumn("Title"); 

// Add data frames. Does not work as it will add only
// keys existing in both data frames
dfTotal += dfIndexed
```

**Table 1**

```
Date,ID,Title,Sales,Market
2014-03-01,ID1,Title1,1,US
2014-03-01,ID1,Title1,2,CA
2014-03-03,ID2,Title2,3,CA
```

**Table 2**

```
Date,ID,Title,Sales,Market
2014-03-02,ID1,Title1,2,US
2014-03-03,ID2,Title2,2,CA
```

**Expected Results**

```
Date,ID,Title,Sales
2014-03-01,ID1,Title1,3
2014-03-02,ID1,Title1,2
2014-03-03,ID2,Title2,5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach with using tuples makes sense.

It is a bit unfortunate that there is no easy way to specify default values when adding!
The easiest solution I can think of is to realign both series to the same set of keys and use fill operation to provide defaults. Using simple series as an example, something like this should do the trick:

```
var allKeys = seris1.Keys.Union(series2.Keys);
var aligned1 = series1.Realign(allKeys).FillMissing(0.0);
var aligned2 = series2.Realign(allKeys).FillMissing(0.0);
var res = aligned1 + aligned2;
```